# Selenium unable to find element SOMETIMES

Tags: python, selenium, find, element

I'm trying to scrape a list of URLs:

> https://www.jobsbank.gov.sg/ICMSPortal/portlets/JobBankHandler/SearchDetail.do?id=JOB-2016-0010810
>   https://www.jobsbank.gov.sg/ICMSPortal/portlets/JobBankHandler/SearchDetail.do?id=JOB-2015-0374997

Using this code, with selenium webdriver

```
def jobdesc(link):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(link)
    jobname = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h3').text
    print "job title" + " " + jobname
    postingdate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/p[1]').text
    print "posting date" + " " + postingdate
    expirydate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/p[2]').text
    print "expiry date" + " " + expirydate
    jobid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/p').text
    print "job id" + " " + jobid
    location = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/dl[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/p[1]').text
    print "location" + " " + location
    category = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/dl[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/span[1]').text
    print "category" + " " + category
    industry = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/dl[3]/ul/li/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/span[1]').text
    print "industry" + " " + industry
    emptype = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/span[1]').text
    print "emptype" + " " + emptype
    workhrs = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li/span[1]').text
    print "workhrs" + " " + workhrs
    shiftpattern = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul[3]/li/span[1]').text
    print "shiftpattern" + " " + shiftpattern
    salary = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul[4]/li/table/tbody/tr/td/span[1]').text
    print "salary" + " " + salary
    joblevel = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul[5]/li/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/span[1]').text
    print "joblevel" + " " + joblevel
    yearsofexp = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul[6]/li').text
    print "yearofexp" + " " + yearsofexp
    vacancyno = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[2]').text
    print "vacancyno" + " " + vacancyno
    jobadviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[4]').text
    print "jobadviews" + " " + jobadviews
    jobapplicants = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[6]').text
    print "nojobapplicants" + " " + jobapplicants


    driver.switch_to_frame('frameJobDescription')
    jobdesc = driver.page_source
    jobdesctree = html.fromstring(jobdesc)
    jobdesctrees = jobdesctree.xpath('//*[@id="divMainJobDescription"]//text()')
    print jobdesctrees

    driver.switch_to_default_content()
    driver.switch_to_frame('frameSkillsRequired')
    jobskills = driver.page_source
    jobskillstree = html.fromstring(jobskills)
    jobskillstrees = jobskillstree.xpath('////*[@id="divMainSkillsRequired"]//text()')
    print jobskillstrees
```

Sometimes when I try to scrape one url, Selenium is able to retrieve all the required fields. However, when I put the scraping into a loop which tries all url, it quickly stops working in the 2nd url, and returns this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\jobsbank15012016.py",
> line 123, in <module>
>     main()   File "E:\jobsbank15012016.py", line 120, in main
>     jobdesc(url)   File "E:\jobsbank15012016.py", line 59, in jobdesc
>     postingdate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/p[1]').text
> File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 252, in find_element_by_xpath
>     return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 684, in find_element
>     {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 195, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 170, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/p[1]"}
> Stacktrace:
>     at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///c:/users/anon/appdata/local/temp/tmprizeob/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10299)
>     at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///c:/users/anon/appdata/local/temp/tmprizeob/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10308)
>     at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/anon/appdata/local/temp/tmprizeob/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12282)
>     at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/anon/appdata/local/temp/tmprizeob/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12287)
>     at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/anon/appdata/local/temp/tmprizeob/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12229)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you should give it some time for the page to load by adding a [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits). You should also simplify your locators and make them less dependent on the HTML structure:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(link)

# wait until title is present
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.title")))

job_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h3.title").text
```

Here, for the job title we are using a simple CSS selector - basically finding an `h3` element with a `title` class. The XPath alternative here would be `//h3[contains(@class, 'title')]`.